# django problems with css

Tags: python, css, django, web

having trouble linking css to my django project, right now im just a beginner and learning how to use the framework. i dont really know whats important and what's not so i'll put the full code. i checked some tutorials and did what they did but it still didn't work i tried some stuff from the documentation and still no luck. Can someone help me out.

heres the settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerce_site project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'wfudi*u9lch97-&tq*sq+_5fi0u&e3khi@iy^(tzg9znkdql)s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'store'
]


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates' )],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

)
```

heres the html file im trying to link it too.

```
{% load static %}

can someone please help me out
<!DOCTYPE html>




<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>STORE</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

)
```

it should be **DIRS** not **DIR**.

and change the base_dir:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

also change database:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: i tries that but it says BASE_DIRS is not defined

Comment: edited my answer.check it and tell me if i am right.

Comment: i did that but theres now issues with other stuff

Comment: what stuff?tell us so we can help.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

Comment: for this line it says that there is an issure

Comment: you had to clarify base_dir in your database.

Comment: so the errors are gone but the css is still not loading

Comment: i need to see your project tree.

Comment: sure just uploading to github